# Converting byteArray to Multipart data in java

Tags: java, file-upload, multipart

I am trying to read a data from a chunk and converting it to byte array at gateway layer of application.

Now this chunk data is POST method with form-data , that consists of 2 parameters , a JSON string.
and Multipart data that is an image.

So , the purpose of me try to read the data that is being pushed as chunk encoding  for manipulating this JSON string and appending a extra key:value to it (example : attaching log id to it)

Now the problem is once i convert the data from chunk to a byte array.
then i'm unable to create the multipart data with same format.

So is there anyway to fetch the multipart form data with a string paramter and then again reverse the process to once the manipulation is done in java.